# A better way to write multi line text

Tags: kotlin

I have created a multi line text that defined as follows:

```
fun main() {
   val t = "SELECT g.description, a.gender_abbr, count(a.gender_abbr)" +
           " from accounts a inner join genders g on g.abbr = a.gender_abbr" +
           " group by a.gender_abbr, g.description"
   print(t)
}
```

Is there a better way to write multi line string?

I have also tried:

```
fun main() {
   val t =  """
           SELECT g.description, a.gender_abbr, count(a.gender_abbr)
           from accounts a
           inner join genders g on g.abbr = a.gender_abbr
           group by a.gender_abbr, g.description
         """.trimIndent()
   print(t)
}
```

But it does not yield the same result.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘better’, and why are the differences in the latter (embedded newlines, I guess) significant here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use triple quotes `"""` but the string will be treated as a string literal, so the newline `\n` and spaces will be shown in the result.

How to solve this? Add a replace statement!

- `.replace("\n\\s+".toRegex(), "")` removes a newline and all whitespaces after that

[image]

Note: all whitespaces after the newline are removed, so add one at the line before. It is debatable whether this is less of an effort than adding `+` operators, but for large stings it may be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own extension function if you prefer the way you tried to make it better.

```kotlin
fun String.trimNewline() = trimIndent().replace("\n", " ")
```

Then use it like so:

```kotlin
val t =  """
    SELECT g.description, a.gender_abbr, count(a.gender_abbr)
    from accounts a
    inner join genders g on g.abbr = a.gender_abbr
    group by a.gender_abbr, g.description
    """.trimNewline()
print(t)
```